# How can I use formidable module in node js to get input type text data from a html field?

Tags: node.js, formidable

How can I use formidable module in node js to get input type text data from a html field? I only get example for file upload. I need other fields like input type text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using callback for the parsed data, all fields and files inputs will be present in `fields` and `files` parameters respectively.

If you want to access specifically input text fields, you can access it in `fields.your_text_field` it will you the value of `your_text_field`.

For more clarity you can try to print data present in `fields`.